# New to JSON API how to access the values in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, api

Below is my code to access the JSON API from Edmunds.com, this works perfectly to access the information I am just having trouble with accessing the key, value pairs.

```
NSURL *equipmentURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/styles/%@/equipment?fmt=json&api_key=%@", self.carID, apiKey]];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:equipmentURL];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    self.engineArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSArray *equipmentArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"equipment"];

    for (NSDictionary *carInfoDictionary in equipmentArray) {

        NSArray *attributes = [carInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"attributes"];
        NSLog(@"%@", attributes);

    }
```

In the NSLog from the above code shows this:

```
2016-11-03 10:21:26.029 CarWise[25766:1896339] (
        {
        name = "Engine Immobilizer";
        value = "engine immobilizer";
    },
        {
        name = "Power Door Locks";
        value = "hands-free entry";
    },
        {
        name = "Anti Theft Alarm System";
        value = "remote anti-theft alarm system";
    }
)
```

My main question is how can I access the name and value for each array? Let's say I want to create a UILabel that will have the string of one of the values?

Comment: What problem are you having? You've gotten down to the array of attributes? What's stopping you from going further?

Comment: I suppose I don't know how to call them? After getting the NSArray how do I get the value for say Power Door Locks? I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: You already have a bunch of code that digs down in other dictionaries and arrays so it seems you should know how to dig into the dictionaries of this `attributes` array. Iterate the array to get each dictionary. For each dictionary, use the `name` and `value` keys to get their values.

Comment: I don't know why it is clicking now, maybe all it took was someone to simplify it a little for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this will help

// Array as per the post

```
NSArray *attributes = (NSArray *)[carInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"attributes"];
```

// Loop to iterate over the array of objects(Dictionary)

```
for (int i = 0; i < attributes.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary * dataObject = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)attributes[i]];

    // This is the value for key "Name"
    NSString *nameData = [NSString stringWithString:[dataObject valueForKey:@"name"]];

    NSLog(@"Value of key : (name) : %@", nameData);

}
```